# Updating multiple rows of one column from multiple values from second column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to update many rows of a table that is already partially populated. The AREA_TITLE column has area names that contain the state name, but never on it's own, hence the %% modifiers. Here is my mysql query that doesn't contain errors (according to Sequel Pro) but won't actually update the table either:

```
UPDATE localTable
SET PRIM_STATE =
CASE AREA_TITLE
WHEN '%Alabama%' THEN 'AL'
WHEN '%Alaska%' THEN 'AK'
WHEN '%Arizona%' THEN 'AZ'
WHEN '%Arkansas%' THEN 'AR'
WHEN '%California%' THEN 'CA'
WHEN '%Colorado%' THEN 'CO'
WHEN '%Connecticut%' THEN 'CT'
WHEN '%Delaware%' THEN 'DE'
WHEN '%Florida%' THEN 'FL'
WHEN '%Georgia%' THEN 'GA'
WHEN '%Hawaii%' THEN 'HI'
WHEN '%Iowa%' THEN 'IA'
WHEN '%Idaho%' THEN 'ID'
WHEN '%Illinois%' THEN 'IL'
WHEN '%Indiana%' THEN 'IN'
END
WHERE AREA_TITLE IN ('%Alabama%', '%Alaska%', '%Arizona%', '%Arkansas%', '%California%', '%Colorado%', '%Connecticut%', '%Delaware%', '%Florida%', '%Georgia%', '%Hawaii%', '%Iowa%', '%Idaho%', '%Illinois%', '%Indiana%');
```

Many thanks for any help!

Sample Data: AREA_TITLE = "Northeast Alabama Non-Metro Area" -> PRIM_STATE = 'AL'
AREA_TITLE = "Central Arkansas Non-Metro Area" -> PRIM_STATE = 'AR'

Comment: Can you add some sample data of the table in your post ?

Comment: Just added sample data

Comment: It would be better to have a table with states in it and join to that.

Comment: @Donal I do have a separate table for states, but I'm not sure what you mean using a join on that. You mean something like a SELECT for pulling the list of XX states for the xxxxxx AREA_TITLE fields? BTW an effective answer has been posted so if you have no interest in following through I understand.

Comment: @ZanderFields I have posted a suggestion below - have not tested it though.

Comment: @ZanderFields http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e45c/1/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I mainly use SQL Server, but this should still apply unless I'm mistaken)

This format of the `CASE` statement will compare the variable with the provided value for each `WHEN`. You should use [the second form](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) of the `CASE` statement, where each `WHEN` defines a condition and specifically uses the `LIKE` operator.

The same goes for your `WHERE` clause, you're actually comparing the values in the table with the literal `%Alabama%`. The `LIKE` operator is needed, and you'll probably need to use several `OR` instead of the `IN` operator.

Something like this :

```
UPDATE localTable
SET PRIM_STATE =
CASE
WHEN AREA_TITLE LIKE '%Alabama%' THEN 'AL'
WHEN AREA_TITLE LIKE '%Alaska%' THEN 'AK'
WHEN AREA_TITLE LIKE '%Arizona%' THEN 'AZ'
WHEN AREA_TITLE LIKE '%Arkansas%' THEN 'AR'
WHEN AREA_TITLE LIKE '%California%' THEN 'CA'
WHEN AREA_TITLE LIKE '%Colorado%' THEN 'CO'
WHEN AREA_TITLE LIKE '%Connecticut%' THEN 'CT'
WHEN AREA_TITLE LIKE '%Delaware%' THEN 'DE'
WHEN AREA_TITLE LIKE '%Florida%' THEN 'FL'
WHEN AREA_TITLE LIKE '%Georgia%' THEN 'GA'
WHEN AREA_TITLE LIKE '%Hawaii%' THEN 'HI'
WHEN AREA_TITLE LIKE '%Iowa%' THEN 'IA'
WHEN AREA_TITLE LIKE '%Idaho%' THEN 'ID'
WHEN AREA_TITLE LIKE '%Illinois%' THEN 'IL'
WHEN AREA_TITLE LIKE '%Indiana%' THEN 'IN'
END
WHERE AREA_TITLE LIKE '%Alabama%' OR AREA_TITLE LIKE '%Alaska%' OR AREA_TITLE LIKE '%Arizona%' OR AREA_TITLE LIKE '%Arkansas%' OR AREA_TITLE LIKE '%California%' OR AREA_TITLE LIKE '%Colorado%' OR AREA_TITLE LIKE '%Connecticut%' OR AREA_TITLE LIKE '%Delaware%' OR AREA_TITLE LIKE '%Florida%' OR AREA_TITLE LIKE '%Georgia%' OR AREA_TITLE LIKE '%Hawaii%' OR AREA_TITLE LIKE '%Iowa%' OR AREA_TITLE LIKE '%Idaho%' OR AREA_TITLE LIKE '%Illinois%' OR AREA_TITLE LIKE '%Indiana%');
```

Comment: Awesome thanks for digging in here, for your second suggestion regarding LIKE, I tried changing to WHERE AREA_TITLE LIKE... and get a 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)' error.

For your first suggestion, it was also not firing. Here's an example of that: WHEN AREA_TITLE LIKE '%Alabama%' THEN 'AL'

Comment: @ZanderFields in where clause you have compare your field with each string like `AREA_TITLE LIKE '%Alabama%' OR AREA_TITLE LIKE '%other value%'...`

Comment: Yes! The 'Something like this: ' is what I began implementing just prior to your posting @Jonathan M and it worked! Thanks so much!

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid thanks to you as well for jumping on this, your answer was spot on as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested it with a sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e45c/1/0)

```
create table states
(
    StateName varchar(100),
    Abbreviation varchar(5) 
);

create table localTable
(
    PRIM_STATE  varchar(100),
    AREA_TITLE  varchar(100)
);


insert into localtable(AREA_TITLE, PRIM_STATE) values ('Northeast Alabama Non-Metro Area','');
insert into localtable(AREA_TITLE, PRIM_STATE) values ('Central Arkansas Non-Metro Area','');

insert into states(StateName, Abbreviation) values ('Alabama','AL');
insert into states(StateName, Abbreviation) values ('Alaska','AK');
insert into states(StateName, Abbreviation) values ('Arkansas','AR');


update localtable 
set localtable.PRIM_STATE = (
    select states.Abbreviation 
    from states where 
    localtable.area_title LIKE CONCAT('%', states.StateName, '%')
);
```

Comment: Very interesting, I'll have to give this a shot. Thanks Donal!